# Double boot doesn't work - Windows 10 / Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

i bought this new notebook (Acer E5-573G-58B7) with Windows 10.
I'm trying to install Ubuntu and make a dual boot, so I followed this steps:

- *Download Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS;*
- *Use one USB to make a boot device;*
- *Shrink my HD with other partition to install Ubuntu;*
- *Restart Windows and boot on USB;*
- *Install Ubuntu in the partition made before;*

Untill now, no problems. The problem comes now.

When i restart my notebook it just go right to Windows, without GRUB or something, i searched a lot, and already disable SECURE BOOT and everything.
And even if i hit F12 when computer starts to boot menu, that screen doesn't show the Ubunutu partition to select and i cant choose Ubuntu to start anyway.

Comment: Please read this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m ! It might help you a lot, because you will find some important and useful information to prepare the Acer Aspire E5-573G series notebook BIOS / UEFI and the Windows setup for getting ubuntu successfully installed. :)

Comment: IT WORKSSS!! MAN, I LOVE YOU <3

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling, but reinstall windows as well...

1. Create an Ubuntu bootable usb
2. Clean out your drive completely (Remove all partitions)
3. First install windows and leave some free space for ubuntu
4. Then reboot a couple of times, and then boot into a usb and install ubuntu into the free space by creating a partition and swap

Another thing you could do is here:
http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: Re-install should not be required. See unique issues to Acer in link posted above by cl-netbox.