# install for acer r3 131t Boot repair did not work

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

hello I did the instructions for efi booting and doing alongside windows.
I have acer r3 131t 32gb model with 2gb ram
I have a 64db sd card and installed there.

it has windows 10 installed (not so bad for $250)
I followed the instructions without doing a windows restore disk because there is no data partition on a 32gb disk!

I got as far as the boot repair but it still did not "repair" it.  It did not instruct me to paste anything.
However I pasted the code from the website below which is also in the "linux user" web page instructions.
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

The uploaded bootrepair is on
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14348507/

So I cannot boot into ubuntu 15.10
It luckily still boots into windows.

I did not see any way to delay the boot time in the bios.
I set the boot order to the main disk first.
There is not a choice to boot from sd, but something is surely in the efi partition for ubuntu.  I can see it.

any suggestions.  Please email me in addition to posting here(I am a monk in myanmar).
bksubhuti-atthegma1l  (figure it out)
will edit this out later.

Just a small complaint:  Why can't the install program do this right and why are there all of these help guides?  I am technical and patient.. but how can Ubuntu spread with things like this.  The install program should have a help guide in it.  If you need to do something else... then tell them to do it.

Comment: I ran bootrepair one more time.  It appears that the boot repair is asking me to set my boot to the disk1 not disk0.  This means it wants me to boot using the sd card.  This is not an option.  This is the problem.  So how to fix this?  I did "something else" and installed grub on the disk0 option.  There is no room on the main disk 32gb.  It chose sd and formated it for me with a swap partition.  windows 10 seems to use way too much disk space and grows each week.  only 6gb available with virtually no data on the main disk.  only a small selection of sw.

Comment: Do not know if your model needs to downgrade UEFI, but all Acer require you to set password and enable trust on the ubuntu efi files. Acer E5-573G, downgrade UEFI, supervisor password & trust on Ubuntu efi boot files.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912 and: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947

Comment: I did that. I am not legacy boot.  Boot repair wants me to set boot to disk1.  Bios does not let me do that

Comment: Boot-Repair's script shows sda as installer flash drive. And grub normally wants to install to drive as sda. So use of a memory card confuses it. Grub is small and usually fits into the same ESP - efi system partition as Windows without issue. And if booting from memory card you then can copy all of /EFI/ubuntu to memory card's /EFI/ubuntu folder. You may have to create that. And then copy again to /EFI/Boot folder on memory card's ESP and rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi. External drives boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and shimx64.efi needs all the files in /EFI/ubuntu to correctly work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem. 
I am not sure 100% the exact cause because I ran boot repair advanced options but that never worked until I did things below:

I read a little bit of the boot repair link I posted and the first comment response helped something clicked after fooling with the bios.
By lucky guess I saw the enable trusted uefi and clicked on it.  Through several clicks..I got to the Ubuntu boot file.  There were several (other than efi backups) probably from many boot repairs.  I selected all of them.  That was cool but it still did not get grub to load.
However I got the grub to boot by the f12 choose boot.  3 choices showed up on the menu this time instead of just Windows.  The third one labeled "1 Yes" worked.
Then I went back to the f2 for general bios and saw "EFI File Boot 1:  Yes" and another with "0" instead of "1" at the bottom of the boot order.  These were familiar new options which I now could see for the f12.
(Before enabling trusted efi, these options were not there)
I may have disabled tpm state too (whatever that is).  It is disabled now and may have been enabled before.  That might also be a cause.

As far as I know through trial and error:
0yes means boot the operating system on mmblk0  (Windows)
1yes means the other disk on mmcblk1 (Ubuntu).
But it could just be the number of boot filled I created with boot repair.  However the "0" file does not boot grub.

Moving "EFI File Boot 1: Yes" to the top of the boot order makes grub boot automatically.  So my work has just begun.  Thanks for helping.

So now I have Ubuntu 15.10 fully installed on my sd (no casper stuff).  It is much better than a live USB.  I just cannot use my SD slot which is no problem.
Ubuntu idles on ½ gb of my 2gb of memory.

In retrospect due to what I write above,  I am not 100% sure grub is on mmblk0p1 (efi) as I said before.
When Grub first did not work, I installed again choosing "something else" and maybe missed the boot install option (though I doubt it and I did a "something else" installation twice to make sure.