# Acer - Win10 & Ubuntu dual booting

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I have also an Acer Aspire VN7-592 G with Windows 10 pre-installed.
I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Win 10 in dual boot, but no matter what version I put 14, 15, 16 at boot I have no option of booting Ubuntu in the boot menu in UEFI mode.
Secure boot is disabled as well.
If I try to boot it in Legacy mode, and choose Ubuntu the PC is freezing.
I have no idea how can I fix this so that I can have Ubuntu and Win 10 alongside in dual boot.

Any help would be apreciated.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: All Acers require you to set a supervisor password in UEFI and set "trust" on grub/shim efi boot files. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13419141#post13419141 and now newest UEFI works, so you do not have to downgrads: http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Windows fast startup under Power options and reboot in UEFI mode.

Comment: I did it. In fact with that I have started the installation. I think it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Which software to create live USB? I tried Rufus under Windows with no success. If you have the possibility to use Ubuntu to create the boot device try this guide [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media). The CLI method worked great for me.

Comment: I use PenDrive and Lili USB creator. I succeded to install ubuntu but the problem is that it is installed on my partition D( I have  partitions) but at boot it enters directly in WIndows 10 and there is no way to get Ubuntu in the Boot Menu

Comment: Did you set a partition for grub? In UEFI dual boot you shouldn't set this, grub automatically recognize EFI Windows partition and installs inside of it.

Comment: I only  boot from the USB key than I followed the steps for a normal installation. I choosed the other partition drive( I have two partitions in win10 C: and D:) and then it got installed. At reboot I couldn't find Ubuntu in the boot menu because it went to Windows 10. Also  there is also no wifi connexion for Atheros in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Do you still see D: in win 10?

Comment: Yes, of course. I updated the post with the image. On the NTFS one is still Windows files but on the other part on D there is UBUNTU

Comment: It'll never boot! You cannot install Ubuntu on NTFS partition. Partition for UEFI are all primary. You should entirely erase your D: then set a partition for SWAP and an EXT4 partition as mount point for Ubuntu. From the image it seems you have two physical disks, I don't know if there are any particular precautions to take in that case. In a typical scenario Windows cannot see partitions dedicated to Ubuntu system.

Comment: I forgot, in dual boot EFI partition it's only one.

Comment: I don't understand. And if I install it on the C partition alongside Windows? THere are tutorials on this on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcHt6OGrIJA

Comment: Min 1:56 the author of the video shrinks Windows partition to obtain some unallocated (free, not partitioned) space to install Ubuntu on. During the installation process Ubuntu choose the unallocated space to install swap and / on and automatically installs grub in Windows EFI partition which is assigned to boot systems.

Comment: So better to install Ubuntu on the same partition as with Windows?

Comment: You can also install OSes on two separate disks. Each system will be completely isolated from each other. It's mandatory that EFI was the first partition on the disk. So your Disque 1 is bad configured. Try reading this [link](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/10/31/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-15-10-on-two-hard-drives/). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There were some ways to deal with this:

First of all if at all you have installed it under 'UEFI'. Then there will be a way to get to that 'EFI' installation.

According to my knowledge (My laptop) there will be a way through bios.

Go to 'Bios settings' as per your computer. Then go to 'Boot options'.
There you should see 'EFI' option.

Then select Ubuntu from it. (I think you will be met with several options please check them one after other)

If you don't like this, I think under 'EFI' in boot-menu you have one option to sign the keys. (It takes merely 5 to 7 seconds to sign keys) (This done from 'EFI' under 'BIOS' Your operating system will not be loaded to do this)

Then Reboot your system, you will be met with choosing of operating system from windows menu.
If this didn't work for you.

Once you check-out this application 'Easybcd'. Try it, I Think this will work for you. It makes a indirect link to the 'MBR Partition' so that you can boot from other drives as well.

But for 'Easybcd' to work your boot-loader should be installed on that respective drive.

I hope this was helpful.