# Unable to get Ubuntu working in Acer Aspire E5-573

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I have managed to install `Ubuntu 14.04` on my laptop using the bootable Pendrive.

After the installation, It asked me to restart, when I did that, I am getting the `GNU grub` where It asks me again If I want to install Ubuntu or just want to try without installing.

So to fix I thought maybe I should put my HDD as 1st priority which I did but even then I am getting that Grub thing.

Please help.

Comment: Unplug the installation pendrive and reboot.

Comment: it then gives no bootable device screen..

Comment: What option did you use to install? Automatic mode or "Something else" (manual partitioning)?

Comment: Automatic mode is whai i went with

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Make sure you have newest UEFI from Acer. Some threads discuss downgrading UEFI, but others say newest works. Acer Very latest UEFI/BIOS works, downgrade not required:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13419141#post13419141
Acer E5-573G, downgrade UEFI, supervisor password & trust on Ubuntu boot files
http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912
Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

Firstly have to know , your laptop maybe support UEFI or not. I think
it's support UEFI . so you have to make it EFI support Ubuntu64 bit iso. 
Download Rufus - iso maker.You need Windows PC.  select " GPT for UEFI" and format "fat32 default" and Rufus create EFI supported iso for your machine.
now boot and install and lastly go to BIOS setting and name Ubuntu for 
boot softly . Thats all . Ubuntu works fine .