# How to install Ubuntu onto Acer Aspire V5-122P Laptop

Tags: aspire

I just received the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS USB stick.  I wish to install Ubuntu onto an Aspire V5-122P currently running windows 10. What would be the step by step method to accomplish installation?

Comment: Make sure you have the newest UEFI. You will have to set supervisory password and set trust once installed: Acer Very latest UEFI/BIOS works, downgrade not required:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13419141#post13419141
Acer E5-573G, downgrade UEFI, supervisor password & trust on Ubuntu efi boot files.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912

Answer (score 0):

You have to boot Your laptop from USB. You should have Boot menu on F12 but if not look this instruction http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3182/~/why-cant-i-get-the-f12-boot-menu-to-work-on-my-notebook-or-netbook%3F 
When You get Boot menu choose Your usb. You can install Linux next to Windows or You can format whole disk for Linux. Read instruction carefully.

When You install Linux, probably You lost access to partition recovery!