# Windows 10 update boots directly to Windows

Tags: updates, boot-repair, grub-efi

Yesterday I had to use Windows after weeks of just using Ubuntu 16.04, and there was a update that made it boot directly to Windows.

I tried bootrepair, and got this pastebin http://paste2.org/U5PpMwFh

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Windows may on updates reset itself to first in UEFI boot order and may turn back on fast start up or always on hibernation. Also since Acer did you set a supervisory password and enable trust on grub's efi boot files. List of UEFI entries shows multiple unknown devices. Acer E5-573G, downgrade UEFI, supervisor password & trust on Ubuntu efi boot files.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912

Comment: I tried checking if fast startup was enabled again, but now I cant find it in the power button menu. Also I did set a supervisor password to disable secure boot, because when I installed Ubuntu it made the grub menu not appear. 
I checked that secureboot is disabled, but I did not understand what you meant. Is there anything I can do to able to get grub back?

Comment: Look at the last six lines of your bootinfo-summary and try if this solves the problem.

Comment: Is your UEFI the newest available. LInk I posted was older and was suggesting downgrading UEFI, where newer links to mention updating to newest is better. If trust is set on Ubuntu files so you can boot, you can use efibootmgr to change boot order. http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr You can also use efibootmgr to delete duplicate UEFI entries. See `man efibootmgr`

Comment: I tried bcdedit, but it did not help. There is a newer BIOS version, I may try that if changing efibootmgr is not working. I will liveboot a session and try changing the boot order to see if it fixes anything. Thanks!

Comment: Do not use BCDedit!

Comment: Well I am livebooting from my USB drive now, and this is what I get when I type sudo efibootmgr -v 
http://imgur.com/IrEQpxh

Why does it say unknown device.. and can I change anything here so it boots from it?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using this command in Windows: "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi" - https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/

Now my grub menu is working fine. Thanks all!