# Getting a black screen when installing or Live booting Ubuntu 16.04 with BIOS v1.25

Tags: acer

I have an ACER Aspire laptop. Model number is E5-573G-56RG. Kept getting black screen and checked this post [Getting a black screen when installing or Live booting Ubuntu (any version) in my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m) and he said to downgrade from bios v1.25 to v1.13. you no longer have to do this, acer came out with an update and i can confirm that all you have to do now is upgrade to v1.37 from acer's website http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers I was trying to post this in the comments but the dumb ass rules wont let me. anyways, this is much easier than downgrading and probably better since there are a lot of fixes lost by downgrading.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but answering the question would have been more appropriate than posting a new 'question'.  Once you gain enough reputation, you will be able to comment.  Calling names is not a good start for that.

Comment: i didnt realize i could answer questions. i dont understand why you cant comment but you can answer. dumb af if you ask me and i didnt call anyone names, why do you have to be a dick?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE BIOS TO v1.37 and ubuntu will boot. get it from here http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers and install it in windows. ubuntu will boot after off of a USB for sure.