# How to install Ubuntu onto an Acer Aspire E5-511P-P0MT laptop that will not load windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, acer

So about a year ago, my old Acer laptop had a free upgrade to Windows 10. Everything was legit, it was from Microsoft, Acer had listed my laptop as eligible to do the upgrade based on their tested in factory, and all was supposed to go well.

Turns out, about a week after I updated (if that) my laptop started to go slow. All of a sudden I open it up one day and it gives me a blue screen, followed by a boot up where it doesn't move past the Acer logo (first screen upon boot up).

So I have tried literally everything... For Windows anyways. So a friend had told me to try Ubuntu and it works where Windows won't. Now the only question is this:

My laptop can go into the F2 Settings menu upon startup, and well that's pretty much it. It wont load past the Acer logo, however when I put a Windows boot USB in it works to install, but not fully. It will not and can not install because "This disc may fail soon". So it can load up the boot USB, however it cannot install anything.

I never once fiddled with any hardware, it never had any major drops, and I never kept it plugged in and always had it run out its battery at least once per month (when it was working). So I have not done a single thing to "damage" the hard drive, however I have read up that a program may have changed the HDD to a different type of memory or something. I have no clue how to check this, or if it even matters (I assume it would have been the W10 upgrade that did this).

So is it still possible to upgrade to Ubuntu? If so, how? I don't care if I lose all information, as I am pretty sure it is lost already. I have erased and formatted "Drive 0" a number a times so I am pretty sure its all gone anyways.

Additional: It had Windows 8.1 before, upgraded to Windows 10, and now I am unsure which it has, if any.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does sound like a drive failure

Comment: How would one test this? I can delete partitions and add new partitions, but I just cannot install Windows... I am going to TRY Ubuntu, but I dont know if it will work :$

Comment: boot a LiveCD of ubuntu. use the try ubutu options. there should be HDD diagnostic tools to test the drive

Comment: Be sure to boot in UEFI mode and know that Acer requires after install that you set UEFI password and enable "trust" on Ubuntu/grub .efi boot files. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot newer threads say newest UEFI from Acer works, so do not downgrade, but make sure you have newest UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912

Answer (score 0):

Based on my personal experience, all you need is a Ubuntu install CD (and test can be done within the installation procedure as ravery suggested). The preparation reference is https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-from-cd.html