# Transplanted SSD between 2 laptops, graphics gone worse, not better

Tags: graphics, video, framerate

I've moved an SSD from an older laptop to newer one. Cinnamon installed on Ubuntu Server, 20.10 and upgraded to 21.04 (I prefer that method to getting the Cinnamon remix distro)

Older laptop
Acer Travelmate 5735
Intel Core2Duo T6670
GM45 Chipset (GMA4500 Graphics)
Tux stenciled on the lid

Newer laptop
Acer Aspire E5-532
Intel Pentium N3700 CPU and IGP

Newer laptop graphics performance worse than old one.
Video playback single digit fps (YouTube and local x264 files)
Desktop (dragging a window around) similar fps

The only thing I've changed is to disable a .conf file in my X11 directory that enabled the brightness control in the *old* laptop.

I have pendrives with Xubuntu and Kubuntu, booted off them, and graphics performance is as expected, smooth.

I did an experiment to see if it is because my pendrives boot up in UEFI and my SSD boots in legacy; I tried converting my install to UEFI (with GPT and new partitions and all that entails) failed and restored from back-up via Clonezilla. Meh. I think I have a very fussy UEFI when it comes to secure boots.

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Best practice is to cleanly install the OS when making a hardware change.  Your old laptop is very different from your new one. Installation media is designed to boot on all hardware, your installed OS is more likely to have software and configs tailored for that particular machine.  The fact that your performance is better in a live session is a good indication that you would probably benefit from a new installation of Ubuntu

Comment: I'm confused. Is this a laptop being used as a server? Because that won't have any graphics installed. Is it a server install you are converting to a laptop with graphics front-end? Technically you can do this manually, but you would be well advised to do a clean install. And if you are transplanting an SSD boot disk from one laptop to a second then do a clean install. It is unlikely to have all the correct modules and may well have some of the incorrect one. Be pleased it works at all! I suggest that you have your /home directory on a separate partition. This way you can do a reinstall withou

Comment: I mention that it was server edition in case it had any bearing on a reply. That is how I like to install Cinnamon, from CLI (not from any other desktop, and not from Ubuntu cinnamon remix, a non-official distro). It has never been used as a server.  And if there's a way to do this without clean install, I want to find it. Is rather learn something doing it an unconventional way than an easy way.

Comment: Acer UEFI mode requires extra settings over standard UEFI which requires more settings than old BIOS type installs. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot  & Acer Very latest UEFI/BIOS works, downgrade not required if no trust screens, you must now upgrade:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13419141#post13419141 & Older: http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912